# Запрос данных в Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Собираю установочник в Inno Setup: добавил необходимое ПО - JRE, MySQL, все отлично, теперь необходимо после установок дополнительного ПО запросить у пользователя логин и пароль для поднятия БД на сервере. Видел что есть этапы установки - но найти конкретный пример не могу.

Сам вопрос, как в Inno Setup после установки дополнительного ПО сделать кнопку "Далее" и открыть форму для ввода логина и пароля...

Собственно для чего это необходимо: установку всего в фоне я сделал, но у пользователя уже может быть сервер MySQL, и чтобы поднять на нем базу необходимо запросить пароль и логин пользователя... Вроде это можно сделать через CurrStep - но как не могу найти...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы создать форму для ввода логина и пароля, вам нужно в скрипте создать свою страничку для мастера установки и указать после какой стандартной странички она должна появляться. Если вы хотите спрашивать логин и пароль после установки, то вашу страничку нужно показывать после `wpInstalling` или `wpInfoAfter`.

Страничка создается, например, так:

```
[code]
var
  LoginPassPage: TWizardPage;
  LoginEdit: TNewEdit;
  PassEdit: TNewEdit;

// обработчик нажатия кнопки Next на нашей страничке
function OnLoginPassPage_NextButtonClick(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
var
  Login, Pass: string;
begin
  Login := LoginEdit.Text; // здесь лежит введенный логин
  Pass := PassEdit.Text; // здесь лежит введенный пасс

  // здесь можно с ними что-то сделать

  Result := True; // можно продолжать установку
end;

procedure CreateCustomLoginPassPage;
var
  LoginLabel: TLabel;
  PassLabel: TLabel;
begin
// Создание страницы задания логина и пароля
  LoginPassPage := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, 'CustomPageCaption', 'CustomPageText');
  LoginPassPage.OnNextButtonClick := @OnLoginPassPage_NextButtonClick; // обработчик нажатия кнопки Next

// логин
  LoginLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  LoginLabel.Parent := LoginPassPage.Surface;
  LoginLabel.Left := 0;
  LoginLabel.Top := 0;
  LoginLabel.Caption := 'Login:';

  LoginEdit := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  LoginEdit.Parent := LoginPassPage.Surface;
  LoginEdit.Left := 0;
  LoginEdit.Top := LoginLabel.Top + LoginLabel.Height + 6;
  LoginEdit.Width := 200;

// пасс
  PassLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  PassLabel.Parent := LoginPassPage.Surface;
  PassLabel.Left := 0;
  PassLabel.Top := LoginEdit.Top + LoginEdit.Height + 6;
  PassLabel.Caption := 'Pass:';

  PassEdit := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  PassEdit.Parent := LoginPassPage.Surface;
  PassEdit.Left := 0;
  PassEdit.Top := PassLabel.Top + PassLabel.Height + 6;
  PassEdit.Width := 200;
  PassEdit.PasswordChar := '*';  // пароль можно прикрыть звездочками
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  CreateCustomLoginPassPage;
end;
```

Comment: а как можно из поля передать тот же пароль далее в установку, если форма ввода будет в `wpInfoAfter`?

Comment: Никак, если форма будет в `wpInfoAfter`. Вы же спрашивали как запросить пароль **после установки ПО**. Если вам нужно запросить данные до установки дополнительного ПО, то поменяйте `wpInfoAfter` на что-то что там по справке идет раньше. Поскольку переменные `LoginEdit` и `LoginPass` глобальные, то к ним можно обратиться в любой удобный вам момент. Если вы хотите передать логин и пасс инсталлятору MySQL, но не знаете как, то для этого лучше всего будет создать новый вопрос.

Comment: хорошо, сегодня вечером попробую)) понемногу вникаю в это дело) еще бы доков адекватных - уже пару недель по кусочкам собираю...

Comment: Вполне адекватные доки есть на официальном сайте InnoSetup. http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/

Comment: Есть еще очень полезная IDE для разработки инсталляков на InnoSetup. https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio